# ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vendor")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resourcebundle

I wrote a new app, which will use an existing theme, which is going to be changed by designer.

So I decided, instead of putting scripts in Scripts and everything else in Content (Css, images), to just keep the theme in Theme folder (with subdirs - js, css, img)

So I try to change the scripts bundling to point to my scripts in Theme/js instead of Scripts

I changed it to

```
bundles.Add(
          new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/sammy-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/toastr.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/Q.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/breeze.debug.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/moment.js")
          );
```

What I don't understand is line

```
new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vendor")
```

If I leave it this as above (even if there is no Scripts/vendor folder, code works ok, but f I change it to

```
new ScriptBundle("~/Theme/js/vendor")
```

I get network error in firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:51154/scripts/vendor"
```

and rest of the scripts are not loaded.

What that line does?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bundles.Add(ScriptBundle)` method adds a script bundle to the bundles table, to which you can refer by the string provided to the `ScriptBundle(string)` constructor.

So a bundle created with `new ScriptBundle("~/Foo")` and added to `bundles`, can later be rendered using `@Scripts.Render("~/Foo")`.

What you probably forgot is to change `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/vendor")` in your _layout.cshtml to `@Scripts.Render("~/Theme/js/vendor")`, and that will be the error you saw.

The parameter you pass to the constructor is merely [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj646517.aspx) as *"a virtual path for the bundle"*, so you'll have to figure out what that means and what you can and cannot put there.

Comment: Right, I didn't changed the dle when rendered. Doing it fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I fixed it by making sure there was no overlap between the alias i used in ScriptBundle(xx) and my actual file system (in your case Theme/js is the same path between the bundle and your Included scripts.

The ScriptBundle class packages up all the included js files into a single minified bundle. This single bundle is downloaded and is more efficient than several independent GET calls. Note that if you're debugging your solution and running your site under the debugger in VS the bundle is not delivered to aid debugging, instead discrete js files are sent to the client. The bundle is served only when `<system.web\><compilation debug="false" ...>`.

Comment: Yup, I had the same thing. A directory existed with the exact same name as the alias, which will prevent the ScriptBundle from working. Make sure the alias name is unique and non-existing.

Comment: "... served only when" *when*?

Comment: :) just updated the answer, i'd forgotten to escape the text as its got angle brackets in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a `ScriptBundle` that is identified as the string value "~/Scripts/vendor" and can be rendered using this bundle identifier.

When you `Include(...)`, this value is represents the relative path to the resource that you want include with that bundle.

```
bundles.Add(
          new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/sammy-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/toastr.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/Q.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/breeze.debug.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/Theme/js/moment.js")
          );
```